# Postgres 9.6: Insert into view with on conflict

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-view

I have 2 tables both with unique constraints, 1 view that joins those 2 tables and an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that allows `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on the view.

Everything works perfectly for regular `INSERT` or `UPDATE` but if I do `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT(tableAColumn,tableBColumn) DO UPDATE` then I get the error:

```
[42P10] ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

If the view was automatically updatable then I think I could just use a `WITH CHECK OPTION` but how do I do that with a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger?

Or another way to ask how do I make the view have the same constraints as the tables it is built from?